# Hibernate: Mapping "Other" column in a collection cross reference table

Tags: hibernate

My object model contains 2 objects of interest, a RuleGroup and a Rule

My RuleGroup object contains a Set of Rules.

Therefore, I have a cross reference table called RULE_GRP_MEMBER that maps between the RULE_GRP table and the RULE table to specify which Rules belong to a RuleGroup.

My RuleGroup mapping file is as follows, and this works fine with no problems.

```
<class name="a.b.c.d.RuleGroup" table="RULE_GRP">
    <id name="ruleGroupID" column="RULE_GRP_ID">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <set name="rules" lazy="true" cascade="save-update" table="RULE_GRP_MEMBER">
        <key column="RULE_GRP_ID" not-null="false"/>
        <!-- Unique set to true makes this a one to many relationship -->
        <many-to-many unique="true" column="RULE_ID" class="a.b.c.d.Rule"/>
    </set>
....
</class>
```

My Rule mapping file does not contain any references to a RuleGroup object.

The problem is that we are now introducing a new non-null field RULE_SEQ onto the RULE_GRP_MEMBER table. So, when a new Rule is added to a RuleGroup, a new row will be added to the RULE_GRP_MEMBER table.

How do I go about mapping this RULE_SEQ field to my objects? Ideally I'd like to map it to my Rule object, but I'm not sure 
what Hibernate concept I should even use.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you might need to create a POJO for join table which contains the columns of the join table.This will have a composite key RULE_GRP_ID, RULE_ID. The new column seq should be ideally defined in this new HBM since it belongs to join table.

Then you can add set mappings to this from RULE, RUL_GRP tables.

Comment: Yes, this is the approach we took eventually. Did not see any easy alternative